# QTableWidget update items

Tags: c++, qt

I’m having trouble with updating QTableWidgetItems. I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong :(

code and explanation.

Step by step problem.

1. at first insertion = OK, all first cells are filled.
2. updating firstly inserted items = OK, all first cells are updated.
3. at second insertion = OK, all second cells are filled.
4. updating second inserted items = OK, all second cells are updated.
5. updating first inserted items = FAIL, all first cells are updated, but NEXT cell’s first table is empty. WHY?

Code:

```
void MainWindow::fillTable(QList<QByteArray> Info)
{
    int Row = ui->clientsList->rowCount() - 1; //Starts from 0.

    //Check if client row already exists.
    for(int i = Row; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(ui->clientsList->item(i, 0)->text().contains(QString(Info[1])))
        {
            //Update row.
            for(int u = 0; u < Info.count() - 1; u++)
            {
                ui->clientsList->setItem(i, u, new QTableWidgetItem(QString(Info[u + 1])));
            }

            return; //avoid new row insertion.
        }
    }

    //Insert new row.
    Row = ui->clientsList->rowCount() + 1;
    ui->clientsList->setRowCount(Row);
    for(int i = 0; i < Info.count() - 1; i++)
    {
        //Fill rows.
        ui->clientsList->setItem(Row - 1, i, new QTableWidgetItem(QString(Info[i + 1])));
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed, sorry! Though it will be also seen by community..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not full solution yet, but few comments:

1.There may be memory leak in line

```
ui->clientsList->setItem(i, u, new QTableWidgetItem(QString(Info[u + 1])));
```

why not use

```
 ui->clientsList->item(i, u)->setText(QString(Info[u + 1]));
```

which is safer and more clear.

2.My understanding is you are relying on the fact that Info has same length as the row length is, perhaps it worth to add check for that?

Comment: My bad! Info.count() was more than columns so it gave access violation. Your example showed me that, thank you! :D

Comment: Even when putting it in Update Row part only, not for new row insertion? If so, are you sure that the length of your Info list is always same - perhaps, it changes from time to time, that is why you occasionally have empty cells?

Comment: Code in `setItem` **doesn't** leak memory see documentation: `The table takes ownership of the item.`